# Problema con carpeta public

Tags: javascript, nodejs, reactjs

Estoy desarrollando una app con back en NodeJs y Front con React.
Una vez terminada la app compilo el proyecto con npm run build el cual me genera la carpeta de archivos estaticos.

Para enlazar esto al back lo hago mediante la siguiente linea

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'../front/build')));
```

Pero las imagenes no se me muestran porque no tengo la carpeta public expuesta.
Y no puedo definir dos veces **express.static**

En este caso cual seria la solucion? subir las imagenes al servidor del front? o como puedo tomar las imagenes de la carpeta publica?

Actualmente estoy mostrando las imagenes de la siguiente manera

```
<img width="200" height="200" className="rounded mx-auto" style={{ objectFit: 'cover' }} src={`/img/uploads/${img.img}`} />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pude resolverla colocando 2 lineas de static

```
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../front/build')))
```